# Is there a way to deploy Blazor Web Assembly if I checked the ASP Net Core Hosted Option?

Tags: azure, blazor

I have been trying to deploy my app to Azure, and I am confused about which one should I publish the client or the server.

Comment: The server project will contain the client project.

Answer (score 0):

As Kirk said in his comments, you need to publish the server project, because as the name indicates, that project is on charge to host the cliente app (in this case the blazor app), however, you can deploy just the client app and publish it on a static web site or static web app if you want to try other options.